# update VS Workflow

Tags: workflow

I've created a worflow in VS. The workflow contains a feature which points to the elements xml file of the workflow.

I've seen a few guides about updating workflow but they are not consistent. 
http://spmat.blogspot.co.uk/2010/11/assembly-versioning-for-sharepoint.html
and
http://blog.philwicklund.com/fff/2010/06/sharepoint-workflow-versioning-with-visual-studio-2010.html

The latter link mentions creating a feature but in the steps there is no mention of this, then I find myself stuck on 1E.

Could someone help with how to update a workflow.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to avoid Workflows because they can be difficult to update.

I instead use [event receivers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg749858.aspx) instead. If the process changes you can just update the WSP file which will deploy the new DLL.

The obvious downside to this is you lose the advantage of allowing current workflows to finish under one set of rules while new workflows start using the new set of rules. This can be accomplished with event receivers but it isn't as straight forward as a process.

I know this doesn't directly answer your question but I thought this could be a potential alternative for you.